# JavaScript DOM - How to allow user to only select one option

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm making a rock, paper, scissors game with HTML, CSS, and JS DOM. I have 6 buttons that allow you to choose how many rounds you want to play. I want it so that when you click on one of them, it gets darker. Then when you click another, that one becomes darker while the previous one returns to its lighter color. Does anyone know how I would implement this? Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
// Changes button color when clicked
let rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".rounds");
rounds.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", () => {
        i.style.cssText = "color: gray; border-color: gray";
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#rounds {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 0.2fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 0.2fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.rounds {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 8px white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.rounds:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgray;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="rounds">
    <button class="rounds">Best of 1</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 3</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 5</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 7</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 10</button>
    <button class="rounds">Custom</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: radio buttons maybe ?

Comment: I'll make sure to try that.

Comment: Only one radio button in a group can be selected at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
// Changes button color when clicked
let rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".rounds");
rounds.forEach(i => {
    i.addEventListener("click", () => {
        [...rounds].map(el => el.style.cssText = "color: white; border-color: white");
        i.style.cssText = "color: gray; border-color: gray";
    });
});
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#rounds {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 0.2fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 0.2fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.rounds {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 8px white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.rounds:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgray;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="rounds">
    <button class="rounds">Best of 1</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 3</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 5</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 7</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 10</button>
    <button class="rounds">Custom</button>
  </div>
```

Tip: Try to toggle class name instead changing css

Comment: It works perfectly! However, I'm a little confused by this part: [...rounds].map(el => el.style.cssText = "color: white; border-color: white");
        i.style.cssText = "color: gray; border-color: gray";  Is it okay if you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: ```[...arrayLikeObject]``` - converting array-like object to array using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Operatory/Spread_operator);
```el => el.style.cssText = "color: white; border-color: white"``` - set styles exactly how you did it, but with different color

Answer (score 0):

Add a loop that reverts the colors of all the other buttons.

It would be easier if you used classes for this, rather than assigning `cssText`.

```js
// Changes button color when clicked
let rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".rounds");
rounds.forEach(i =>
  i.addEventListener("click", () => {
    rounds.forEach(r => r.classList.remove("active"));
    i.classList.add("active");
  })
);
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#rounds {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 0.2fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 0.2fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.rounds {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 8px white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.rounds:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgray;
  border-color: lightgray;
}

.rounds.active {
  color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div id="rounds">
  <button class="rounds">Best of 1</button>
  <button class="rounds">Best of 3</button>
  <button class="rounds">Best of 5</button>
  <button class="rounds">Best of 7</button>
  <button class="rounds">Best of 10</button>
  <button class="rounds">Custom</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps to your proyect, only one radio button in a group can be selected at the same time, for example:

```html
<input type="radio" name="rounds" id="1">Best of 1
<input type="radio" name="rounds" id="3">Best of 3
<input type="radio" name="rounds" id="5">Best of 5
<input type="radio" name="rounds" id="7">Best of 7
<input type="radio" name="rounds" id="10">Best of 10
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use classes you could use the div eventlistener to listen for the button trigging the event and then loop through the element set them to white and the button to grey
to set the color ofa button in javascript you do `element.style.color="white"`

```js
// Changes button color when clicked

let rounds = document.querySelectorAll(".rounds");
buttons=document.getElementById("rounds")
  buttons.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
rounds.forEach(i => {
     i.style.color=" white"         
     i.style.borderColor="white"

});
    e.target.style.color = "gray";
    e.target.style.borderColor= "gray"
   
});
</script>
```

```css
* {
  color: white;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: black;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#rounds {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 0.2fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 0.2fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.rounds {
  background-color: black;
  font-size: 25px;
  border: solid 8px white;
  outline: none;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

.rounds:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: lightgray;
  border-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="rounds">
    <button class="rounds">Best of 1</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 3</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 5</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 7</button>
    <button class="rounds">Best of 10</button>
    <button class="rounds">Custom</button>
  </div>
```